# How to set IsChecked = True for a Radio buttons that are generated from an Enum WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have generated RadioButtons from an enumeration as follows.

```
 <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="GetRadioTypes">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Enums:RadioTypes"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetRadioTypes}}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RadioButton  Margin="10" GroupName="MyRadios" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"  Content="{Binding}" >
                         </RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Now i am interested to Check the first RadioButton generated defaultly. 
How can i do that??

If i have IsChecked = "True" for the RadioButtton in ItemTemplate it by default Checks everyone that generates which i dont want to happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you change your itemscontrol to, say, a list box you'll have access to the SelectedItem property. Bind that to a property in your viewmodel,SelectedRadio (or whatever), and then set SelectedRadio to the first enum in your vewmodel's constructor.

Comment: If i change to ListBox how do i bind the SelectedItem to a RadioButton's IsChecked property??

I see that only first item being selected but The Radio button inside it is "NOT CHECKED". How do I bind from ListBox to RadioButton's IsChecked property?